# How can we check the liveness of any image using Cognitive Face API Services?

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-cognitive-services

We are developing attendance app using Xamarin Forms and FACE API of Cognitive services. What we are doing is like this.

1. **Registering Photo** : When user clicks on this button we open the mobile camera , user click his/her photograph and then we submit that image to Face API . No issue in that we have successfully implemented/registered the same using Cognitive Face API services.
2. **Verify User** : When user clicks on this button again we open the camera, user click his/her photograph and then we send this image to FACE api for verification . No issue in that we have successfully implemented the same.

**Now what issue we are facing is :-**

On verification button, user shows  his/her old saved photograph to camera and click its photo not the real live image. Obviously that matches the same and got verified successfully. Here we always want to take his/her live photo not the fake one because its attendance application also used to field staff. Any body can fool the app.

We want to stop clicking the fake images. We want to track liveness of the photo. If something available at camera level which can tell user not to show fake photos , show real live photo.

Any help/response is highly appreciable.

Regards

Prem Sharma

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [headpose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cognitive-services/face/face-api-how-to-topics/how-to-use-headpose) attribute to detect a person rather than a image while using a live stream or camera and passing the images to face API. There is a sample WPF application on [github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-dotnet-sdk-samples/tree/master/app-samples/FaceAPIHeadPoseSample) on how it can be used.

Comment: We have mobile app developed in xamarin form . We are using Xamarin.Essential to open the Camera on both the platform. In that, it is not getting implement.